# How do I transfer my photos from Flickr to Picasa?

Tags: flickr, picasa-web-albums

I have been using a Flickr Pro account for a few years, but find it really annoying that I don't maintain a local offline record of my albums and metadata with this. So I've decided to move to Picasa - where I have an offline app to set up, edit and then upload photos and albums. The challenge is that I have around 100 albums in Flickr and want to get them across to Picasa.

- Do I need to use a Flickr downloader to put them all in a folder and then add them to Picasa?
- Is there a way I can match the uploaded files with the local files on my computer so I don't end up with a load of duplicates?
- Can I transfer the metadata (e.g. geolocation) across? If so, how?

Hope you can help because my only other method is to do it all manually!

Comment: New beta version of Windows Live Gallery has support for importing and syncing metadata with flickr.

Comment: In the end, what I did was go through each album in Flickr and recreate manually in Picasa. Why? you might ask. Because I already had all the photos on my hard disk and wanted Picasa to know which ones from which folder were uploaded, rather than having a separate set of folders. It's a year on and I've not quite done them all yet! :)

Comment: Try [picaflicka](http://www.picaflicka.com/) they offer free service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a tool called [**Migratr**](http://www.callingshotgun.net/about/migratr/), which [makes it easy to transfer your pictures](http://www.lostintechnology.com/windows/how-to-transfer-photos-from-flickr-to-picasa) from Flickr to Picasa or vice versa.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome... will have to give it a go :)

Comment: Hrm, just installed it and it seems you can't choose which photos to download - you just have to grab the lot. That could take a long time for all my photos and could bust my download cap :( Shame I can't just select which albums to start with.

Comment: I've been just trying to use Migratr and getting rather frustrated with it. Export from Flickr went well, but uploading to Picasa is problematic. It doesn't propagate privacy settings - that's annoying but I can deal with. The main issue is that when it crashes, it doesn't handle resuming uploads well. Since the photos are not uploaded in the same order as the albums, it's hard figure out what's been already uploaded and what hasn't. And it doesn't check if the photo already exists, so I end up with duplicates. Also, it hasn't been updated since 2009 and the forums are full of spam.

Comment: @Eugene do you suggest I withdraw my answer then? Because its no good keeping bad answers?

Comment: @Ivo, it does seem to work for some people. I'm just giving a fair warning.

Answer (score 1):

If Migratr didn't work out for you, try [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr). It will let you select photos/sets you want to download and much more.

Comment: I really like Bulkr. I've used it for several years, just downloading as backup from Flickr.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [digiKam](https://www.digikam.org)? It's a desktop application which allows you to sync a local copy of images (and metadata thereof) with [Picasa Web](https://www.digikam.org/node/394), [Flickr](https://www.digikam.org/node/346), [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:KIPI_uploader) and much more.