# Flickr to Picasa migration on a Mac

Tags: flickr, picasa-web-albums

I am looking for a way to migrate all of the photos from a Flickr account to a Picasa (soon to be Google Photos) account. I would prefer not to have to download all of the files to my local hard drive and then re-upload them.

Another question covered this same ground ( [How do I transfer my photos from Flickr to Picasa?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79/how-do-i-transfer-my-photos-from-flickr-to-picasa) ) but the accepted solution is for Windows. I need a Mac solution.

Obviously I'd like to keep the meta data.

Comment: This is not an app recommendation request. This is asking _how_ to do it. If it's an app, fine, but I'm just looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that there is nothing available that will easily do this for Mac users.

I did find [this blog post](http://www.edparsons.com/2011/06/migrating-from-flickr-to-picasaweb/) which seems fairly easy. It does depend on you having Python installed though.

> **Extracted from blog post**
>
> The key component to the migration was a [python script](http://nathanvangheem.com/scripts/migrate-flickr-to-picasa-nokey.py) I found
>   developed by [Nathan Van Gheem](http://nathanvangheem.com/) last year, which used both services
>   api’s to migrate not just pictures but albums and much of their
>   metadata between the services.
>
> So here we go, these instructions are for  mac users who are in the
>   lucky position of having python installed by default, but for windows
>   are pretty similar are you have [installed Python.](http://www.python.org/download/windows/)
>
> From a terminal window, install the two photo service api’s and the
>   threadpool packages for Python
>
> ```
> easy_install-2.6 gdata
> easy_install-2.6 flickrapi
> easy_install-2.6 threadpool
> ```
>
> To use the python script you will need to authenticate against each of
>   the services to access your pictures, for picassaweb this is your
>   username and password, for Flickr because you are using in effect an
>   external application to access your pictures you will  need a Flickr
>   API Key and secret.
>
> From your Flickr account go the [App Garden](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/) and apply for your own
>   non-commercial API key. You need to provide a few details, but will
>   end up with the api key  string and a separate secret key string,
>   something like..
>
> ```
> Key: e97df11b147f9c46c2ec002b29f479df
> Secret: 8fe34c331abbce32
> ```
>
> Now you have all you need..
>
> Remember to make your downloaded script executable
>
> ```
> chmod +x migrate-flickr-to-picasa-nokey.py
> ```
>
> And run it
>
> ```
> migrate-flickr-to-picasa-nokey.py
> ```
>
> You should be asked to enter firstly your picassweb details, then your
>   flick api key and secret, you should then be taken to a flickr webpage
>   to confirm you want the script to have access to your pictures.
>
> ```
> This script will move all the photos and sets from flickr over to picasa.    
> That will require getting authentication information from both services...    
>
> Authenticating with Picasa...
> Picasa Username(complete email):edparsons@gmail.com
> Picasa Password:
> Authenticating with Flickr..
> Flickr API Key:e97df11b147f9c46c2ec002b29f479df
> Flickr API Secret:8fe34c331abbce32
> Press ENTER after you authorized this program
> ```
>
> Confirm that it’s ok, go back to the terminal window and press enter
>   for the script to continue.
>
> The process will take some time, so go grab a coffee and look forward
>   to seeing your pictures in picasweb !

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced it myself but the webapp **[Showzey](http://showzey.com)** seems to do that (for free).
The full procedure is explained here : [How to Move Photos From Flickr to Picasa Web](http://www.ehow.com/how_8775389_move-photos-flickr-picasa.html).

If for some reason it doesn't work for you, and you fallback to a manual approch, then desktop app **[Photo Grabbr](http://www.malarkeysoftware.com/projects_PhotoGrabbr.html)** (donationware) is of some help to download full sets of photos from Flickr.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find a solution yet, you can try Cloudsfer.com
Cloudsfer is a web service for migrating files between clouds and it supports both Flickr and Picasa.

Full disclosure - I'm part of the Cloudsfer team